# OTRS 6 AuthSyncModule::LDAP Integration

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ldap, centos7, otrs

I'm in the process of trying to integrate our current LDAP users into OTRS 6 on a Centos 7 server (we're upgrading from OTRS 2.4.5).  I'm trying to use the AuthSyncModule which will take the current LDAP users from our LDAP server and sync them into the OTRS database. The code below is what I'm currently using:

```
 $Self->{'AuthModule::UseSyncBackend'} = 'AuthSyncBackend';
 # agent data sync against ldap
 $Self->{'AuthSyncModule'} = 'Kernel::System::Auth::Sync::LDAP';
 $Self->{'AuthSyncModule::LDAP::Host'} = 'xxx.xxx.co.uk';
 $Self->{'AuthSyncModule::LDAP::BaseDN'} = 'dc=xxxxx6,dc=xxt';
 $Self->{'AuthSyncModule::LDAP::UID'} = 'uid';
 $Self->{'AuthSyncModule::LDAP::SearchUserDN'} = 'uid=xxxx,ou=xxxxe,dc=xxxxx6,dc=xxt';
 $Self->{'AuthSyncModule::LDAP::SearchUserPw'} = 'some_password';
 $Self->{'AuthSyncModule::LDAP::UserSyncMap'} = {
      # DB -> LDAP
      UserFirstname => 'givenName',
      UserLastname  => 'sn',
      UserEmail     => 'mail',
 };

 $Self->{'AuthSyncModule::LDAP::UserSyncInitialGroups'} = [
        'users',
    ];
```

In the Maint::Log::Print, it states it cannot find the UserID for a given user:

```
Every 2.0s: /opt/otrs/bin/otrs.Console.pl  Maint::Log::Print                                                                                                                               Fri Dec  1 16:40:51 2017

Fri Dec  1 16:20:18 2017;;error;;OTRS-CGI-42;;No UserID found for 'john.doe'!
Fri Dec  1 16:12:03 2017;;error;;OTRS-CGI-42;;No UserID found for 'john.doe'!
Fri Dec  1 16:11:22 2017;;error;;OTRS-CGI-42;;No UserID found for 'john.doe'!
```

I've been following the OTRS material for Syncing from LDAP into the OTRS database here http://doc.otrs.com/doc/manual/admin/4.0/en/html/external-backends.html#agent-auth-backend-ldap.  There isn't a great deal online surrounding this issue, so I'm kinda at a loose end.

Any help on how I can get this work, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the AuthModule section (for authentication) configure as well ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a rather old question, but I had the same issue (same error message) and the solution was not in OTRS, but on the AD: for the user to be able to authenticate, his/her Directory entry **must** have an email address configured on the "email" field. If you don't do it, even if the user exists on AD and integration is correctly configured in Config.pm, authentication will fail.